# Deleting a record in a SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have coded a few pages to delete a record from a database but it doesnt seem to work.

I have a website where the user logs in using the correct name and password that is stored in a database, this works fine.

This then takes the user to the admin page, the code consists of some of the following:

```
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN genre ON genre.genreID = details.genreID;") or die(mysqli_error($sql));


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {


  echo '<div class="info-box">

  <img class="image" src='.'"'.$row['image'].'"
  '.'>

  <a class="edit" href="delete.php?id=' . $row["ID"] .'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this record?\')">Delete</a>  |



  </div>'; 

} 

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have created a JS fiddle with the full code on the admin page ... http://jsfiddle.net/n3n4ot4g/

This page goes to delete.php behind the scenes to delete the record.  This page consists of the following code:

```
<?php

$myID = $_GET['ID'];

echo $myID;


include ('includes/dbconx.php');


//check if a value has been sent
if(isset($myID)){

//MySQL statement to delete record using the unique id variable
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM details WHERE ID = '$myID'") or die ('Error: '.mysqli_error());

}

mysqli_close($con);


header("Location: admin.php");


?>
```

When i click on the delete link the pop up box appears to confirm the deletion, where i click yes, but then it takes me to admin.php with no content in it.  All the records disappear.  This also happens when i click on "view records" on the left panel navigation.  I can go back and log in again and see the records, but the record i tried to delete will not be deleted.

Im not sure if this is a HTML or PHP problem.

I know JS fiddle is not designed for PHP, but i could not find an alternative.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: use ideone or CompileOnline.com  for your code explaination.

Comment: try to put else statement in second code and check whether session started on not.

Comment: `mysqli_error()` expects the connection object as paramater. Change `mysqli_error($sql)` to `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: is there a reason why you're using mysqli and not PDO?

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM details WHERE ID = '$myID'") or die ('Error: '.mysqli_error());`

to:

`mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM details WHERE ID = " . $myID) or die ('Error: '.mysqli_error());`

By putting `$myID` in single quotes, you're saying that it should be taken as is, so your query is searching for an ID of literally "$myID" which of course it won't find.

Alternatively, you could remove the single quotes and not concatenate the `$myID` variable, making sure that the query itself is still wrapped in double quotes. This means that the variable will be processed properly and the value of it will be used.

`mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM details WHERE ID = $myID") or die ('Error: '.mysqli_error());`

Comment: I tried replacing this line with both your examples but my code is still doing the same thing..

Comment: Change `$myID = $_GET['ID'];` to `$myID = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: This is now working to delete the record! Thanks.  But only problem now is it is not displaying the records after deletion, it should go back to the admin page with all the records but instead the part of the page is blank where the records should be.  Should i create a new question for this problem?

Comment: it's because you're `echo`ing to the page before you run the `header()` method. Header information needs to be set before any content is loaded to the page. Remove the `echo $myID;` and it will work.

Comment: I originally had the echo $myID to check if it was working, but i have removed it and still nothing has changed.